# Querying two Separate Columns in ArcPy SQL {where clause}?

Tags: arcpy, sql, feature-class, where-clause

Using ArcPy I'm Trying to Set up a Where Clause in my "FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion"

This {Where Clause} needs to Query Two Columns in the data:

```
FEATURE = 'ENVIRONMENT'

and 

TEMPERATURE > 50
```

I'm having a hard time doing both queries in the same expression as you would using "AND"

> "\"FEATURE\" = 'ENVIRONMENT'" ?AND?  "\"TEMPERATURE\" > 50"

Comment: PolyGeo Did a great job at answering however, here a is Detail I did not mention (Setting a Range for TEMP): ..... AND " + '"TEMPERATURE" > 50' AND "+'"TEMERATURE" <=100' .......Wondering what I'm missing on this one. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

> '"FEATURE" = ' + "'ENVIRONMENT' AND " + '"TEMPERATURE" > 50'

If so the things to note are that I am concatenating three strings, and in each string I have either a pair of single or double quotes that I need to wrap another pair of the opposite type of quotes around.

There are no triple single quotes in the above but you need to pay close attention to whether I have used the single or double quote first.

Comment: THIS is Detail I did not mention (Setting a Range for TEMP):   ..... AND " + '"TEMPERATURE" > 50' AND "+'"TEMERATURE" <=100' .......Wondering what I'm missing on this one.  THANKS!