# Where Clause looking at two Columns and a RANGE Expression

Tags: arcpy, expression, where-clause, operator

Using ArcPy I'm Trying to Set up a Where Clause with a RANGE in my "FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion"

This {Where Clause} needs to Query Two Columns in the data:

```
FEATURE = 'ENVIRONMENT'

and 

TEMPERATURE > 50 **AND <=100**
```

A slightly simpler example in [Querying two Separate Columns in ArcPy SQL {where clause}?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168176/querying-two-separate-columns-in-arcpy-sql-where-clause) works great but I realized the Range Above is critical.

I think it should be something like below without the "???".

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(FC,LOCATION,"EARTHTEMP",'"FEATURE"='+"'ENVIRONMENT'AND "+'"TEMPERATURE"> 50' ??AND "+'"TEMPERATURE"??? <=100'???)
```

Comment: I am not clear as to what your question is?  You want to know the other SQL command or ???

Comment: Using python and in the ArcGIS Python command line I'm running the script to look at a Feature Class FC  that queries against two columns: FEATURE and TEMPERATURE... for Temperature, it uses a range beween 50° and 100° and For "FEATURE" it uses "ENVIRONMENT"....the new FC it creates Is "EARTHTEMP"...Hope that helps? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to respond to comments requesting clarification. Most data backends (which you didn't specify) support a `BETWEEN` operator, but you may still need to use two (three total) "col op value" constructs ANDed together.

Comment: Just apply the same principles as in the other answer I gave -when I get back to laptop rather than being on iPhone I can quickly do if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but I think it should work:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(FC,LOCATION,"EARTHTEMP",'"FEATURE" = ' + "'ENVIRONMENT' AND " + '"TEMPERATURE" > 50 AND ' + '"TEMPERATURE" <= 100')
```

but this should work too:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(FC,LOCATION,"EARTHTEMP",'"FEATURE" = ' + "'ENVIRONMENT' AND " + '"TEMPERATURE" > 50 AND "TEMPERATURE" <= 100')
```

Comment: @Matthew don't forget to upvote and/or accept answers that help you.